# How to bind Line Charts with Combo box in silverlight?

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, xaml

I am using 2 different line series in chart in silverlgiht application

```
<toolkit:Chart Grid.Column="1"  Grid.Row="2" Height="300" Width="450" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Name="FarmCondtion" Title="Farm Condition" VerticalAlignment="Top" > 
    <toolkit:LineSeries x:Name="TempLine" Visibility="Visible" Title="Temprature" IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Date}" 
                                                DependentValueBinding="{Binding Temp}" ItemsSource="{Binding }"/>
    <toolkit:LineSeries x:Name="MoistureLine" Visibility="Collapsed" Title="Moisture" IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Date}" 
                                                DependentValueBinding="{Binding Moist}" ItemsSource="{Binding }"/>
</toolkit:Chart>
```

and i am using a combo box :

```
<ComboBox x:Name="FarmCombo" SelectionChanged="FarmCombo_SelectionChanged">
            <ComboBox.Items >
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Temprature"></ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Moisture"></ComboBoxItem>
            </ComboBox.Items>
</ComboBox>
```

I want to create an event `FarmCombo_SelectionChanged` in which i want to show only the chart's line serie which is seleted in the combo box.

I used this event as :

```
private void FarmCombo_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
            string selectedItem = FarmCombo.Items[FarmCombo.SelectedIndex].ToString();
            if (selectedItem == "Temprature")
            {
                TempLine.Visibility.Equals("Visible");
                MoistureLine.Visibility.Equals("Collapsed");
            }
            else if (selectedItem  == "Moisture")
            {
                MoistureLine.Visibility.Equals("Visible");
                TempLine.Visibility.Equals("Collapsed");
            }
}
```

But the code doesn't have any effect on the visibility of Line Series.

Please suggest How can i use the Combo Box to choose which Line Series to be shown in the chart ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In your code for the SelectionChanged event you never actually set the Visibility of the line series. All `MoistureLine.Visibility.Equals("Visible");` does is return a boolean value indicating whether the Visiblity is Visible, it doesn't actually set the property.

Additionally the `SelectionChangedEventArgs` contain the value that has been selected so you don't need to reference the combobox itself to get this information.

The following code should more aligned with what you're looking for:

```
private void FarmCombo_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{          
       if(e.AddedItems.Count == 1)
       {
            string selectedItem = e.AddedItems[0].ToString();

            if (selectedItem == "Temprature")
            {
                TempLine.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                MoistureLine.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            }
            else if (selectedItem  == "Moisture")
            {
                MoistureLine.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                TempLine.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Just to double check have you debugged through the code to a) see whether the selectedItem is set to the correct string value? and b) see if the Visibility is being set correctly on the lines?